# When $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a real number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I wrote it this way: $\frac{z-1}{z+1} = \frac{(z-1)(\overline{z}+1)}{(z+1)(\overline{z}+1)}=\frac{|z|^2 + z - \overline{z} -1}{|z+1|^2} = \frac{|z|^2 -1+2iImz}{|z+1|^2}$ and
I calculated that for $|z|=1 $ this quotient $ \frac{z-1}{z+1}$ is a purely imaginary number, but I don't know for which $ z $ it is a real number.

Comment: It is real iff $z\in\mathbb R$. You can show this by considering the inverse Mobius transformation of $(z-1)/(z+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

You've shown that $$\frac{z-1}{z+1} = \frac{|z|^2 -1}{|z+1|^2} +i \frac{2 \operatorname{Im}z}{|z+1|^2}$$
so that the fraction is purely real if and only if $\operatorname{Im} z = 0$ and $z \not= -1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you know the fact that a Möbius transformations sends lines in $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ to lines or circles in $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, then it suffices to check the image of the points $-1,0,1$ under $\phi(z)\equiv(z-1)/(z+1)$. We have $\phi(0)=-1$, $\phi(1)=0$, and $\phi(-1)=\infty$, so it follows that $\phi(\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\})=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$. Since $\phi$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ (and hence a bijection), it follows that $\phi(z)$ is real if and only if $z$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

It is real if & only if it is equal to its conjugate, namely, since complex conjugation is a field automorphism,
\begin{align}
\frac{z-1}{z+1}=\frac{\bar z-1}{\bar z+1}&\iff(z-1)(\bar z+1)=(z+1)(\bar z-1) \\
&\iff z\bar z+z-\bar z-1= z\bar z-z+\bar z-1 \\&\iff 2z=2\bar z,\quad\text{ i.e. }\enspace z=\bar z, 
\end{align}
in other words, if & only if $z$ is real.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $z \ne -1$ and $r \ne 1$, then

$
\displaystyle\quad
\frac{z-1}{z+1} = r  \iff z = \frac{1+r}{1-r}
$

$
\displaystyle\quad
r \in \mathbb R \iff \frac{1+r}{1-r} \in \mathbb R
$